# Translate for else loops to math equation

Tags: logic, algorithms

I wonder how to make math equation based on the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
   if (i % 2 == 0)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
             cout << ”*”;
    else
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
             cout << ”*”;
}
```

**Question**: How many arterisk will be printed after the program is executed? given m = 30 and n = 10.

my answer is 360 arterisks will be printed based on the code above. I have test it by running the program in computer and got the same result. But I want to know how can we write the equation based on the code above.

Comment: Could you perhaps translate that problem into English? Not everybody here can read computer code, including myself. You _are_ on a **maths** board, after all.

Comment: Where are you having problems? Have you asked yourself for which values of `i` the if clause is true and for which ones it is false? How many asterisks are printed in each case? Try adding an `cout << std::endl;` statement before the final curly bracket.

Comment: How many times does it print * when $i$ is even? How many times does it print * when $i$ is odd?  What happens when you add these up for $i$ from $0$ through to $m-1$? (The answer may depend on whether $m$ is odd or even)

Comment: We are asking you these questions because you need the answers to those questions in order to deduce the formula. Insert the `endl` statement I mentioned to help find those answers.

Comment: when you say "algebraic expression", do you mean in terms of summations and mod operators or something else?

Comment: i think yess. So sorry I am a newbie here @Max0815, just preparing for my computer science olympiad in regional level. I want to learn how to count the arterisk without running the program since we are going to use paper later in the competition. So I think that it would be easier for me if I know the mathematical principle for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I think this would better asked in StackOverflow or a similar CS based SE site.

Regardless, you stated that your goal was to "learn how to count the arterisk without running the program".

We simply do this through *tracing*.

Consider the code below

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
   if (i % 2 == 0)
       //code1
   else
       //code2
}
```

We look at the for condition, and see that it is looping $m$ times.

Then, for each iteration, we check if the iteration number/index variable (the second if statement nested inside) is *even* and execute `code1`. Otherwise, we execute `code2`.

Now, let's take a look at `code1` (when $i$ is even)

```
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
         cout << ”*”;
```

This outputs `*` into the console $i$ times.

`code2` (when $i$ is odd) meanwhile

```
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
         cout << ”*”;
```

outputs `*` into the console $n$ times.

Using this information, we can now see what the case of $m=30$ and $n=10$ does.

From $0$ to $29$, there are a total of $15$ odd numbers. This means that the odd index variables contribute to the total `*` count $15\cdot n = 150$ times.

Then, considering the even index variables, which are $0$ through $28$ (there are again $15$ of them), we can see that the number of `*` printed is $$\frac{15\cdot(0+28)}{2} = 210$$

Adding the two cases together results in $150+210=360$ `*`'s printed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Max0815, your solution is very helpful. Now I can make the algebraic expression based on your explanation.